# Change of variable theorem for the curvilinear integral

Tags: complex-analysis, change-of-variable

I have to proof the change of variable theorem for the curvilinear integral, but I have no idea about how to do that, and I haven't found information in Google. The theorem states:

Let be $\Omega$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{C}$ an open subset, $\gamma$ the union of arcs (in spanish it's called path, but I don't know if this word it's used in english), and $\varphi$ an holomorphic function in $\Omega$. 
Then, $\varphi$ $\circ$ $\gamma$ is union of arcs and $\forall$ $f$ continuous function in ($\varphi \circ \gamma$)*, we have:
$\int_{\varphi\circ \gamma} f(z) dz$ = $\int_{\gamma} f(\varphi(w))\varphi(w)' dw$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write these integrals as integrals over a *real interval*, and use the chain rule for differentiation?

Let's suppose that $\gamma$ is parametrised over an interval $[a,b]$. Then

\begin{align} \int_{\varphi \circ \gamma} f(z) \ dz & = \int_{a}^bf((\varphi \circ \gamma) (t)) \ (\varphi \circ \gamma)'(t) \ dt \\
& = \int_a^b f(\varphi(\gamma(t)) \ \varphi'(\gamma(t))\ \gamma'(t)\ dt \\ &= \int_{\gamma} f(\varphi(w))\ \varphi'(w) \ dw. \end{align}

To spell it out:

- In the first line, we use the definition of $\int_{\varphi \circ \gamma} f(z) \ dz $. This complex path integral is *defined* as the integral over the real interval on the right-hand side.
- To get to the second line, we use the chain rule to get from $(\varphi \circ \gamma)'(t)$ to $\varphi'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)$.
- To get to the third line, we again use the definition of a complex path integral in terms of an integral over a real interval. This time, the complex path integral is $ \int_{\gamma} f(\varphi(w))\ \varphi'(w) \ dw$.

Comment: Great, I like your answer. Nevertheless, in the first line you are using the definition of an integral over an arc. As far as I know, when you have a complex path, you have to take the partition $P=\{a=t_{0}<...<t_{k}=b\}$ where the restriction of $\varphi \circ \gamma$ to $[t_{k-1},t_{k}]$ is an arc, and then sum the all the integrals in each restriction. Given that, the proof would follow your steps. On the other hand, how do you proof that $\varphi \circ \gamma$ is a complex path?

Comment: @vicase98 Oh okay, so you are distinguishing between smooth paths (my answer) and *piecewise smooth* paths (your comment.

Comment: As for how you prove that $\varphi \circ \gamma$ is a piecewise smooth path... You know that $\gamma : [t_{k-1} : t_k] \to \mathbb C$ is smooth. And you know that $\varphi : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is smooth. So their composition, $\varphi \circ \gamma : [t_{k-1} : t_k] \to \mathbb C$ is also smooth.